# How to split a list into subsets with no repeating elements in python

Tags: python, list, python-itertools

I need code that takes a list (up to `n=31`) and returns all possible subsets of `n=3` without any two elements repeating in the same subset twice (think of people who are teaming up in groups of 3 with new people every time):

```
list=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

and returns

```
[1,2,3][4,5,6][7,8,9]

[1,4,7][2,3,8][3,6,9]

[1,6,8][2,4,9][3,5,7]
```

but not:

```
[1,5,7][2,4,8][3,6,9]
```

because 1 and 7 have appeared together already (likewise, 3 and 9).

I would also like to do this for subsets of `n=2`. 
Thank you!!

Comment: "All possible" is at odds with "have appeared together already". Why do we choose to include `[1,4,7][2,3,8][3,6,9]` and therefore exclude `[1,5,7][2,4,8][3,6,9]`, rather than the other way around?

Comment: What should it do when the total is not a multiple of the group size? Treat the extras as a smaller group? Rotate them out, but ignore what happens when they're not in a group? Or is that set of conditions not valid input?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. For now, let's assume N is a multiple of group size (N=30, n=3).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. @Thomas: For now, let's assume N=30, n=3.

Comment: @Karl: good point... this is not a point I thought about...but I am fine randomly choosing between the options.

Comment: Is it really split, so for N=15, n=3 it should return 5 groups of 3 per line?

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I came up with:

```
from itertools import permutations, combinations, ifilter, chain

people = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

#get all combinations of 3 sets of 3 people
combos_combos = combinations(combinations(people,3), 3)

#filter out sets that don't contain all 9 people
valid_sets = ifilter(lambda combo: 
                     len(set(chain.from_iterable(combo))) == 9,
                     combos_combos)

#a set of people that have already been paired
already_together = set()
for sets in valid_sets:
    #get all (sorted) combinations of pairings in this set
    pairings = list(chain.from_iterable(combinations(combo, 2) for combo in sets))
    pairings = set(map(tuple, map(sorted, pairings)))

    #if all of the pairings have never been paired before, we have a new one
    if len(pairings.intersection(already_together)) == 0:
        print sets
        already_together.update(pairings)
```

This prints:

```
~$ time python test_combos.py 
((1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9))
((1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9))
((1, 5, 9), (2, 6, 7), (3, 4, 8))
((1, 6, 8), (2, 4, 9), (3, 5, 7))

real        0m0.182s
user        0m0.164s
sys         0m0.012s
```

Comment: Should be the top answer. Succinct and super fast.

Thanks, you helped me create breakout groups for a meeting

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from itertools import permutations

lst = list(range(1, 10))

n = 3
triplets = list(permutations(lst, n))
triplets = [set(x) for x in triplets]

def array_unique(seq):  
    checked = [] 
    for x in seq:
        if x not in checked: 
            checked.append(x) 
    return checked

triplets = array_unique(triplets)

result = []
m = n * 3
for x in triplets:
    for y in triplets:
        for z in triplets:
            if len(x.union(y.union(z))) == m:
                result += [[x, y, z]]

def groups(sets, i):
    result = [sets[i]]

    for x in sets:
        flag = True
        for y in result:
            for r in x:
                for p in y:
                    if len(r.intersection(p)) >= 2:
                        flag = False
                        break
                    else:
                        continue
                if flag == False:
                    break
        if flag == True:
            result.append(x)

    return result

for i in range(len(result)):
    print('%d:' % (i + 1))
    for x in groups(result, i):
        print(x)
```

Output for n = 10:
http://pastebin.com/Vm54HRq3

Comment: Did you test it for N=15, n=3?

Comment: @Fenikso, it works damn slow. I had enough patience to figure out only one sulution: http://pastebin.com/tE7xv0WT

Comment: @Fenikso, why 5? IIUC, OP means "all possible subsets of n=3" for any N.

Comment: 15 divided by 3 is 5. That is my understanding of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt of a fairly general solution to your problem.

```
from itertools import combinations

n = 3
l = range(1, 10)

def f(l, n, used, top):
    if len(l) == n:
        if all(set(x) not in used for x in combinations(l, 2)):
            yield [l]
    else:
        for group in combinations(l, n):
            if any(set(x) in used for x in combinations(group, 2)):
                continue
            for rest in f([i for i in l if i not in group], n, used, False):
                config = [list(group)] + rest
                if top:
                    # Running at top level, this is a valid
                    # configuration.  Update used list.
                    for c in config:
                        used.extend(set(x) for x in combinations(c, 2))
                yield config
                break

for i in f(l, n, [], True):
    print i
```

However, it is very slow for high values of `n`, too slow for `n=31`. I don't have time right now to try to improve the speed, but I might try later. Suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

My wife had this problem trying to arrange breakout groups for a meeting with nine people; she wanted no pairs of attendees to repeat.

I immediately busted out itertools and was stumped and came to StackOverflow. But in the meantime, my non-programmer wife solved it visually. The key insight is to create a tic-tac-toe grid:

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

And then simply take 3 groups going down, 3 groups going across, and 3 groups going diagonally wrapping around, and 3 groups going diagonally the other way, wrapping around.

You can do it just in your head then.

```
- : 123,456,789 
| : 147,258,368 
\ : 159,267,348 
/ : 168,249,357
```

I suppose the next question is how far can you take a visual method like this? Does it rely on the coincidence that the desired subset size * the number of subsets = the number of total elements?